# как обучать модель если использовал KFold cross validation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, машинное-обучение, scikit-learn

после разбиения сета методом ''sklearn.cross_validation.KFold'' у меня есть 6 чанков (3 train ,3 test,+ ответы для них)  . Существует ли функция , с помощью  которой можно обучить алгоритм просто закинуть все чанки или нужно постоянно писать  :

```
Vasya=model.fit(chank1,answer1)
a1=model.predict(Vasya,answer_t_1)
```

?

Comment: Для чего вы используете KFold? Какую модель вы проверяете?

Comment: Дерево решений (доп текст , сорян stakowerflow ,что обманул)

Comment: использую , чтобы шарить + точность выше

Comment: Вы можете дать больше информации в вопросе - код для построения модели и небольшой пример входных данных и объяснить что вы пытаетесь сделать?

Comment: PS на всякий случай напомню: методы из под-модуля `sklearn.cross_validation` применяются для __тестирования__  производительности (точности) существующей модели на всем data set...

Comment: я знаю , что они используются для тестирования . Данные я взял с кеггла . Задача игрушечная и тривиальная (регрессия) на неё можно даже не смотреть . KFold я взял специально , так как просто хотел научиться использовать его в коде . Конечно , без него можно обойтись , но повторюсь  , хочу научиться его использовать

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если хотите научиться пользоваться KFold - вот небольшой [пример](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#k-fold):

```
kf = KFold(n_splits=N)
for train, test in kf.split(X):
    print("%s %s" % (train, test))
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = X[train], X[test], y[train], y[test]
    model.fit(X_train, y_train)
    ...
```

вариант попроще:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score

kf = KFold(n_splits=N)
results = cross_val_score(model, X, y, cv=kf)
```

Comment: Как применить для тестовой выборки полученную модель? То есть в моем понимании надо пройтись по всем коэффициентам модели для каждого фолда, усреднить их, затем создать пустую модель и туда эти коэффициенты занести. И лишь только затем применить к модели. Должен же быть какой-то библиотечный способ из sklearn?

Comment: @Evgeny, посмотрите соседний ответ...

Comment: GridSearchCV перебирает параметры, а мне это не надо. Я лишь хочу узнать как после того, как я получил score для 10 фолдов через cross_val_score можно получить усредненную модель

Answer (score 4):

[Кросвалидация](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html)
встроена в sklearn. Если нужно протестировать модель на разных фолдах с использованием `KFold` то самы простой способ это [cross_val_score](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score.html#sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score) или [cross_val_predict](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_predict.html#sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_predict)

- `cross_val_score(model,chank1,answer1,cv=n)` даст оценки для фолдов
- `cross_val_score(model,chank1,answer1,cv=n)` даст все предсказания по X

Но обычно кросвалидацией подбирают гиперпараметры для этого есть
[GridSearchCV](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html#sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV) которая можно отдать сетку паметров и "сама" подберет лучшуую комбинацию.

**NB** у всех этих функций есть параметр `n_jobs` вот он и стоит того, чтобы не писать циклы ручками `n_jobs = -1` положит машину на время проведения работ загрузив все процы - это, то что в python не так просто сделать.